# Spring Cloug config client doesnt fetch properties from config server

Tags: cloud, client, microservices, config

I'm Learning microservices with Spring Cloud and everything was ok until this point.
It seems that my Config server is working. I have my application.properties at my git hub account and it fetches them from Git Hub. I can also see them on my localhost:8888/application/default or application/master and my hard drive where it stores them. So it seems fine. My Config Server:
pom:

```
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigServer
public class ConfigServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ConfigServerApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

application.properties:

```
spring.application.name=config-server
server.port=8888

spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=https://github.com/account-name/repoName.git
spring.cloud.config.server.git.username=xxx
spring.cloud.config.server.git.password=xxx
spring.cloud.config.server.git.clone-on-start=true
```

Now for the client. It doesn't want to start, cause of empty value in properties. It works when I put the values locally though.
pom:

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Both have:

```
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

I now erased the application.properties for now and have only bootstrap.yml on the client side:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: users-ws
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: http://localhost:8888
      name: config-server
server:
  port: 0
```

The Exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Pattern cannot be null or empty
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:656) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:484) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1336) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1179) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:571) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:531) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:925) ~[spring-context-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:588) ~[spring-context-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:767) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1309) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1298) ~[spring-boot-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
    at luke.photoappapi.PhotoAppApiApplication.main(PhotoAppApiApplication.java:14) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.4.0.jar:2.4.0]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Pattern cannot be null or empty
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:651) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    ... 27 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Pattern cannot be null or empty
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.hasText(Assert.java:289) ~[spring-core-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher.<init>(AntPathRequestMatcher.java:112) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher.<init>(AntPathRequestMatcher.java:97) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher.<init>(AntPathRequestMatcher.java:85) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher.<init>(AntPathRequestMatcher.java:74) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.setFilterProcessesUrl(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:358) ~[spring-security-web-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
    at luke.photoappapi.security.WebSecurity.getAuthenticationFilter(WebSecurity.java:51) ~[classes/:na]
    at luke.photoappapi.security.WebSecurity.configure(WebSecurity.java:45) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.getHttp(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:217) ~[spring-security-config-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.init(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:315) ~[spring-security-config-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.init(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:93) ~[spring-security-config-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
    at luke.photoappapi.security.WebSecurity$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3f58b3b5.init(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.init(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:338) ~[spring-security-config-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:300) ~[spring-security-config-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:38) ~[spring-security-config-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain(WebSecurityConfiguration.java:127) ~[spring-security-config-5.4.1.jar:5.4.1]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    ... 28 common frames omitted
```

It comes from here:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final Environment env;
    private final UserService userService;
    private final BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    public WebSecurity(
            Environment environment,
            UserService userService,
            BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder) {
        this.env = environment;
        this.userService = userService;
        this.bCryptPasswordEncoder = bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .headers().frameOptions().disable().and()  
                .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll()
//                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").hasIpAddress(env.getProperty("gateway.ip"))
                .and().addFilter(getAuthenticationFilter());
    }

    private AuthenticationFilter getAuthenticationFilter() throws Exception {
        AuthenticationFilter authenticationFilter = new AuthenticationFilter(userService, env, authenticationManager());
//        authenticationFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
        authenticationFilter.setFilterProcessesUrl(env.getProperty("login.url.path"));
        return authenticationFilter;
    }
}
```

It cant set FilterProcessesUrl in getAuthenticationFilter() method. I cant get the property `login.url.path`. Of course if i put it into application.properties everyting is fine. I watched three-four tutorials on configuration. I do the same things and nothing is working.
If you see what's up i would be glad for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a problem, the spring team change the default value for enable Bootstrap by default, so this is why it's working if you downgrade, or setting local properties.

The solution from spring cloud:

> Bootstrap, provided by spring-cloud-commons, is no longer enabled by default. If your project requires it, it can be re-enabled by properties or by a new starter.
>
> - To re-enable by properties set spring.cloud.bootstrap.enabled=true or    spring.config.use-legacy-processing=true. These need to be set
>   as an    environment variable, java system property or a command line
>   argument.
> - The other option is to include the new spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap.

[More details](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-release/wiki/Spring-Cloud-2020.0-Release-Notes#breaking-changes)

Comment: We need to add spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap in which POM, the config-server or the clients?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, got it. Everything started working from changing spring boot ver from 2.4.0 to lower 2.2.6 and spring cloud version to Hoxton.SR9 or6. It seems there are some problems with the new ver. Maybe they are changing something.

Comment: What about the new versions. Did you get any fixes for new versions of Spring?